# Как через JS определить, что у пользователя открыты инструменты разработчика?

Tags: javascript

JS-скрипт добавляет блок на сайт. Нужно скрыть блок от тех, кто может просматривать код сайта. В исходном коде блока нет, т.к. создается динамически. Если пользователь открывает в браузере инструменты разработчика, то я отслеживаю изменение размера окна и удаляю блок. Можно ли как-то определить, что до загрузки страницы уже были открыты инструменты разработчика? Считывание соотношения сторон вряд-ли подходит из-за кучи разных вариантов.

Comment: Нет, у браузеров нет API, что открыто, а что закрыто. Да и это не имеет никакого смысла, поскольку клиентскую часть приложения нужно делать максимально безопасной

Comment: Вашу страницу всё равно смогут посмотреть через View page source (Ctrl+U)

Comment: view-sourse не отображает динамически созданные элементы

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7798748/find-out-whether-chrome-console-is-open

Comment: Но пользователь обязательно найдёт способ просто отключить все ваши проверки

Comment: @andreymal спасибо за ссылку. Это не прям для продвинутых нужно. Понятно, что все можно обойти при желании.

Answer (score -1):

Создал функцию, отслеживающую изменения, на основе ответа из https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7798748/find-out-whether-chrome-console-is-open

На 16.01.2019 работает не работает в мозиле.

```js
function watchDevToolOpen(callback) {
  let isOpened = false;
  let isOpen = false;
  let isFirstRun = true;
  var devtools = new Blob()
  Object.defineProperty(devtools, 'size', {
    get() {
      isOpened = true;
    }
  });
  setInterval(function() {
    isOpened = false;
    console.log('%c', devtools);
    setTimeout(() => {
      if (isOpened && !isOpen) {
        isOpen = true;
        isFirstRun = false;
        callback(isOpen);
      }
      if ((!isOpened && isOpen) || (!isOpened && !isOpen && isFirstRun)) {
        isOpen = false;
        isFirstRun = false;
        callback(isOpen)
      }
    }, 100);
  }, 1000);
}

watchDevToolOpen(function(isOpened) {
  document.getElementById('status').innerText = isOpened ? 'open' : 'close';
});
```

```html
<h2>Devtools status is <span id='status'></span></h2>
```

Comment: Но отображается ли это изменение статуса "на другом конце провода"?

Comment: @Олег Что вы имеете в виду?

Comment: Т. е., пользователь у себя открыл консоль, он же увидел **Devtools status is open**, а у владельца сайта всё осталось по прежнему - **Devtools status is close**.

Comment: @Олег В вопросе не было требования отправлять состояние Devtools владельцу сайта (интересно, кто такой владелец сайта?). К тому же, никто не мешает выполнить **любой** код в `callback`.